# Ending Statement Balance in Saved Search

Tags: netsuite

I would like to ask if the Ending Statement Balance in the Reconcile Account Statement form can be pulled to a saved search? Where does this data stored in NS? I will be needing this field for a suitelet report that I am creating. Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qg7PS.png)

Cannot find ways to retrieve it